# What format should data sent to a Google Cloud Functions onCall request be in?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire

I have the most simple Google onCall cloud function:

```
// [START]
exports.echo = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  return {
    value: "echo"
  };
});
// [END]
```

I submit the following in the Google cloud console test:

`{"data":"somedata"}`

I am getting the following error:

`{"error":{"message":"INTERNAL","status":"INTERNAL"}}`

It seems there is an issue with the object that I am passing. Can anyone tell me what the correct format is? What am I missing here?

P.s: I am ultimately trying to connect an onCall function with a client application via Firebase/fire, but that is also giving the same error.

---

Here's the trace:

> /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:349:16 at fixedLen (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:66:41) at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:385:32 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
> Unhandled error TypeError: res.on is not a function at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:350:17 at new Promise () at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:349:16 at fixedLen (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:66:41) at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:385:32 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

---

Here's the index.ts:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
import admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Triggers
import { echo } from "./triggers/echo"

admin.initializeApp();


// Exports
module.exports = {
    // OnCall
    echo: functions.https.onCall(echo)
};
```

Comment: This code looks fine at first glance. Are you sure the message is coming from this code, and not from the client that calls this Cloud Function?

Comment: Hi Frank, (met you a few years back at a Google conf)... I am testing this in the console, to eliminate any issue with the client.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. The arrow function signature was incorrect.
2. `async` is not required for this synchronous response.
3. The correct type of the context parameter is `CallableContext`:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const echo = functions.https.onCall((data:any, context:functions.https.CallableContext) => ({
    value: "echo"
}))
```